# Maximum norm and the triangle inequality

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are two metric spaces then

$d^{\infty}_{X\times Y}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\max(d_X(x_1,x_2),d_Y(y_1,y_2))$ is a metric for $X\times Y$

I have tried to prove the triangle inequaltiy

i.e.:

$\max(d_X(x,x''),d_Y(y,y''))\leq\max(d_X(x,x'),d_Y(y,y'))+\max(d_X(x',x''),d_Y(y',y''))\tag{*}$

But I don't know how. I have first assumed without loss of generality

$d_X(x,x'')\geq d_Y(y,y'')$. Then I have in $(*)$ on the LHS $d_X(x,x'')$ if I could somehow Show that the already made assumptions would implicate that $d_X(x,x')\geq d_Y(x,x')$ and $d_X(x',x'')\geq d_X(x',x'')$ I would be done. But I really don't know how I can make these conclusion.

Comment: This boils down to $\max(a+b, c+d) \le \max(a,c) + \max(b,d)$. Can you show that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since $d_X$ is a metric, then we know that $$d_{X\times Y}^\infty(x,x'')=d_X(x,x'')\le d_X(x,x')+d_X(x',x'').$$ To take it from there, think about how $d_X(s,t)$ and $d_{X\times Y}^\infty(s,t)$ are related, in general.